# Deploy an app in Payara using existing database in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, web, glassfish, payara

I am totally new to Payara and I have question about how can I deploy an app which uses existing database? So I have .war file and .bak file (MSSQL backup).
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you're a little bit confused about Payara capabilities. Payara is an Application Server based on Glassfish, it doesn't matter the kind of database that any of your deployed applications has to access and of course the database should exists.

For MSSQL database you could use *Microsoft JDBC driver*. There's an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-via-jdbc):

On the other hand, it possible to configure a database connection pool in **Payara/Glassfish** server. 
In the official Payara's blog there are interesting posts and one focused on database connection pool that can be found [here](http://blog.payara.fish/an-introduction-to-connection-pools-in-payara-server) .
Don't worry if the article is talking about a derby database, you only has to modify Microsoft JDBC params properly when configurating the pool.

In addition, if you decide to use connection pool it's necessary to made some changes inside your application:

- Change method getConnection() from DRIVER_MANAGER (jdbc) to DATASOURCE

**DRIVER_MANAGER:**

```
        public Connection getConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", DB_USER);
            properties.setProperty("password", DB_PWD);
            properties.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
            properties.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
            if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
                connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+DB_HOST+":"+DB_PORT+"/" + SCHEMA.substring(0, SCHEMA.length() - 1), properties);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return connection;
        }
```

**DATA_SOURCE:**

```
public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", DB_USER);
            properties.setProperty("password", DB_PWD);
            properties.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
            properties.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
            InitialContext ctx;

            ctx = new InitialContext();

            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("database_resource_pool");
            if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {

                connection = ds.getConnection();
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return connection;
    }
```

- Add resource-ref to web.xml

> ```
> <resource-ref>
>       <res-ref-name>database_db_pool</res-ref-name>
>       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>       <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
> </resource-ref>
> ```

- Add resource-ref to WebContent/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml

> ```
>  <resource-ref>
>           <res-ref-name>database_db_pool</res-ref-name>
>           <jndi-name>database_db_pool</jndi-name>
> </resource-ref>
> ```